# copy images from custom field to another custom field

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, post-meta, images

On my wordpress site I have a front end form that allows users to create posts and upload photos for a custom post type 'Property'.

Using the following function -

```
$property_sights_value = get_post_meta($Property_Id, 'imic_property_sights', false);

if (!empty($_FILES['sightMulti']['tmp_name'][0])) {
                    $i = 1;
                    $files = $_FILES['sightMulti'];
                    foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {
                        if ($files['name'][$key]) {
                            $file = array(
                                'name' => $files['name'][$key],
                                'type' => $files['type'][$key],
                                'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key],
                                'error' => $files['error'][$key],
                                'size' => $files['size'][$key]
                            );
                            $_FILES = array("sight" . $i => $file);
                            $newuploadMulti = sight("sight" . $i, $pid);
                            if ($i == 1) {
                                update_post_meta($pid, '_thumbnail_id', $newuploadMulti);

                            }
                            add_post_meta($pid, 'imic_property_sights', $newuploadMulti, false);
                        }
                        $i++;
                    }
                }
        }
```

And then on another page I have the same thing except for a different custom post type 'v_editor', and a different upload function, which converts images to .png format and gets rid of the original -

```
$vid_pix = get_post_meta($v_Id, 'vid_pix', false);

    if (!empty($_FILES['vidPix']['tmp_name'][0])) {
                        $i = 1;
                        $files = $_FILES['vidPix'];
                        foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {
                            if ($files['name'][$key]) {
                                $file = array(
                                    'name' => $files['name'][$key],
                                    'type' => $files['type'][$key],
                                    'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key],
                                    'error' => $files['error'][$key],
                                    'size' => $files['size'][$key]
                                );
                                $_FILES = array("sight" . $i => $file);
    add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'wpse_141088_upload_dir' );
    add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'no_image_resizing');

                            $mfile =  wp_handle_upload($files, $upload_overrides );             

                                $newvidPix = sight("sight" . $i, $v_Id);
    remove_filter( 'upload_dir', 'wpse_141088_upload_dir' );
    remove_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'no_image_resizing');
    // Convert the image to PNG and delete the old image.
    attachment_to_png( $newvidPix );

                                if ($i == 1) {
                                    update_post_meta($v_Id, '_thumbnail_id', $newvidPix);
                                }
                                    add_post_meta($v_Id, 'vid_pix', $newvidPix, false);
                            }
                            $i++;
                        }
                    }
```

Both functions work fine, however, what I am trying to do is--

On the 'v_editor' cpt form, I am trying to create a select dropdown to let the user choose a post of his from the 'property' cpt, and grab the images saved there to copy over to use. --

```
<?php query_posts(array('post_type'=>'property','order'=>'desc','author'=>$current_user->ID,'posts_per_page' => 25,'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),'post_status' => array('publish','pending','draft')));
if(have_posts()): 

echo '<select id="property_posts" name="property_posts">';

while(have_posts()):the_post();

echo '<option value="'.get_the_ID().'">'.get_the_title().'</option>';

endwhile;

echo '</select>';

endif; ?>

<button type="button" id="import_pics">Import</button>
```

Both of the images when uploaded get stored to meta keys -

```
PROPERTY CPT - $property_sights_value = get_post_meta($Property_Id, 'imic_property_sights', false);

V_EDITOR CPT - $vid_pix = get_post_meta($v_Id, 'vid_pix', false);
```

How can I achieve this?

**UPDATE**

This is what I currently have -
On my front end custom post editor form for my `V_EDITOR CPT`, I have the following code that creates a drop down list of the current user's post in the `PROPERTY CPT`, with each of its id and title -

```
<form id="import_photos" action="import-pics.php" method="post" target="_blank">

<?php query_posts(array('post_type'=>'property','order'=>'desc','author'=>$current_user->ID,'post_status' => array('publish','pending','draft')));
if(have_posts()):

echo '<select id="propertyID" name="propertyID">';
while(have_posts()):the_post();
$id = get_the_ID();
$v_title1 = get_the_title($id);

echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$v_title1.'</option>';
endwhile;
echo '</select>';
endif; ?>
<input type="hidden" name="videoID" id="videoID" value="<?php echo $v_Id; ?>">
<input type="submit" id="ip_submit" class="savestuff2" name="ip_submit" value="Import Photos">
</form>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

When a user selects an option and clicks the submit button, a new window opens up and currently shows the photos from that post. This is the import-pics.php script --

```
<?php
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php';

$propertyID = $_POST['propertyID'];
$vidID = $_POST['videoID'];

$query = new WP_Query( 
  array( 
    'post_type' => 'property', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'p' => $propertyID
  ) 
);
$image_query = new WP_Query( 
  array( 
    'post_type' => 'attachment', 
    'post_status' => 'inherit', 
    'post_mime_type' => 'image', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    'post_parent__in' => $query->posts, 
    'order' => 'DESC' 
  ) 
);

if( $image_query->have_posts() ){
  while( $image_query->have_posts() ) {
      $image_query->the_post();
      $filename = basename ( get_attached_file( get_the_ID() ) );
      $imgurl = wp_get_attachment_url( get_the_ID() );

      echo '<div style="display:inline-block;margin:10px;">';
      echo '<a href="'.$imgurl.'"><img style="width:200px;" src="'.$imgurl.'"></a>';
      echo '</div>';
  }
}

?>
```

What I need to do is copy over the images in the `PROPERTY` post type custom field `$property_sights_value` into the `V_EDITOR` post type custom field `$vid_pix`, they are both image attachments. How can I do this using my script?

**UPDATE**

(Trying to get it work with ajax)

My code in my functions.php file --

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_imp_enqueue_scripts' );
function ajax_imp_enqueue_scripts() {

wp_enqueue_script( 'imp', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/imp.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );

wp_localize_script( 'imp', 'imppro', array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
    ));

}

add_action('wp_ajax_imp_pros', 'import_the_photos');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_imp_pros', 'import_the_photos');

function import_the_photos() {

Global $wp_query;
$current_page_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
global $post;
global $current_user;
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

$propertyID = $_POST['propertyID'];
$videoID = $_POST['videoID'];

// Get the attachments (IDs) attached to the `property` CPT.
$prop_att_ids = (array) get_post_meta( $propertyID, 'imic_property_sights', false );

// Copy the meta value (attachments) to the `v_editor` CPT.
$vid_pix = get_post_meta( $videoID, 'vid_pix', false ); // test
//delete_post_meta( $videoID, 'vid_pix' );
foreach ( $prop_att_ids as $att_id ) {
    add_post_meta( $videoID, 'vid_pix', $att_id );
}
$vid_pix2 = get_post_meta( $videoID, 'vid_pix', false ); // test
var_dump( $vid_pix, $vid_pix2 ); // test

// Show a notice to the user.
echo '<p>Photos below have been imported ' .
    'from <i>' . get_the_title( $propertyID ) . '</i> ' .
    'to <i>' .  $videoID . '</i>:</p>';

// And show the attachments.
foreach ( $prop_att_ids as $att_id ) {
    $imgurl = $att_id ? wp_get_attachment_url( $att_id ) : '';
    if ( $imgurl ) {
        echo '<div style="display:inline-block;margin:10px;">';
        echo '<a href="'.$imgurl.'"><img style="width:200px;" src="'.$imgurl.'"></a>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}

die();

}
```

And my JS code --

```
jQuery(document).on('click','#ip_submit',function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

 var propertyID = $('#propertyID').val();
 var videoID = $('#videoID').val();

                    $.ajax({
                      url: imppro.ajax_url,
                      data: {
                       action: 'imp_pros',
                       propertyID: propertyID,
                       videoID: videoID
                         },
                     //processData: false,
                     //contentType: false,
                      type: 'POST',
                      success: function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                        $("#save-order").trigger("click");
                        //$('#loader').hide();
                        //$('#finished').show().delay(3000).fadeOut();
                        }
                    });

        });
```

Comment: I don't see any field named `videoID` in the `v_editor` CPT form? Are you getting the right post ID (`$vidID`) in `import-pics.php`?

Comment: yes. i had it as a static value for testing and forgot to add the input to the form when I changed it for the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### UPDATE #2

In your `import_the_photos()` function, please change this:

```
// Copy the meta value (attachments) to the `v_editor` CPT.
$vid_pix = get_post_meta( $videoID, 'vid_pix', false ); // test
//delete_post_meta( $videoID, 'vid_pix' );
foreach ( $prop_att_ids as $att_id ) {
    add_post_meta( $videoID, 'vid_pix', $att_id );
}
$vid_pix2 = get_post_meta( $videoID, 'vid_pix', false ); // test
var_dump( $vid_pix, $vid_pix2 ); // test
```

to:

```
// Get the attachments (IDs) attached to the `v_editor` CPT.
$vid_att_ids = (array) get_post_meta( $vidID, 'vid_pix', false );

// Copy/add the attachments to the `v_editor` CPT.
foreach ( $prop_att_ids as $att_id ) {
    if ( $att_id && ! in_array( $att_id, $vid_att_ids ) ) {
        add_post_meta( $vidID, 'vid_pix', $att_id );
    }
}

var_dump( $prop_att_ids, $vid_att_ids, get_post_meta( $vidID, 'vid_pix', false ) ); // test
```

*Apologize for the `delete_post_meta()`, which thankfully you commented out..*

---

### Original Answer

*(Old code removed, though.)*

In your `import-pics.php` file, add this *before* the `$query = new WP_Query` line:

```
// Get the attachments (IDs) attached to the `property` CPT.
$prop_att_ids = (array) get_post_meta( $propertyID, 'imic_property_sights', false );

// Copy the meta value (attachments) to the `v_editor` CPT.
// OLD CODE HERE; REMOVED
```

But here's the full code I used, where I don't use the `new WP_Query()` constructs:

```
<?php
// File: import-pics.php

require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php';

$propertyID = $_POST['propertyID'];
$vidID = $_POST['videoID'];

// Get the attachments (IDs) attached to the `property` CPT.
$prop_att_ids = (array) get_post_meta( $propertyID, 'imic_property_sights', false );

// Copy the meta value (attachments) to the `v_editor` CPT.
// OLD CODE HERE; REMOVED

// Show a notice to the user.
echo '<p>Photos below have been imported ' .
    'from <i>' . get_the_title( $propertyID ) . '</i> ' .
    'to <i>' . get_the_title( $vidID ) . '</i>:</p>';

// And show the attachments.
foreach ( $prop_att_ids as $att_id ) {
    $imgurl = $att_id ? wp_get_attachment_url( $att_id ) : '';
    if ( $imgurl ) {
        echo '<div style="display:inline-block;margin:10px;">';
        echo '<a href="'.$imgurl.'"><img style="width:200px;" src="'.$imgurl.'"></a>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}

// Show a "close" JS button..
echo '<p><a href="#" onclick="window.close(); return false;">Back to form</a></p>';
?>
```

*PS: Updated because I forgot the meta `imic_property_sights` and `vid_pix` are added multiple times to a post. Sorry about that.*

Comment: I am trying to use the code as a function in functions.php so I can do it via ajax from my page. It seems to copy everything except the image url. When using as a script, as described in my question, it works fine. Any tweak im missing to get to work with ajax?

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. First, are you using `add_action( '{wp_ajax OR wp_ajax_nopriv}_{ACTION}' )`? Secondly, can you share your AJAX JS code and the PHP function for handling the request, unless you're making AJAX requests to the `import-pics.php`?

Comment: i've updated my question with the code

Comment: Check the `id` attribute, which should be `videoID`, since in the JS code, you use `$('#videoID')`: `<input type="hidden" name="videoID" id="videoId" ...>`. The `id` is *case-sensitive* - I mean, `$('#videoID')` and `$('#videoId')` are referencing to different elements.

Comment: Alternatively, in the JS code, use `$('#videoId')` instead. Or is that `videoId` was just a typo *in the question*? (I hope it's not... means changing it in the HTML/JS code would solve the problem.)

Comment: yes that was just a typo. Everything is using `videoID`

Comment: I've updated the answer. If the problem persists, let me know.

Comment: the code for some reasons messed up the original meta in the original cpt

Comment: @Rich Please let me know if all is good now? Btw, the `$vidID` was actually correct, based on the code *in the question*. =)

Comment: im trying to debug it cause it seems that when deleting a image from one post type, seems to affect the meta in the other post type.

Comment: i figured out why, they share the same attachment url even though i made a copy into a new folder. I might need to open a new question on how to change the attachment url when importing the pics.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/316454/copy-attachments-to-another-post-type-and-change-attachment-url

Comment: @Rich Check my answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/316669/137402).